# Best way to practice Selenium

Tags: testing, selenium

I am trying to improve my skills in Selenium, but I don't want to spend time creating my own sites to test and automating using a normal website I suspect will only cover part of the functionality of Selenium. Therefore, is there a Selenium equivalent of code katas that I could use to hone my skills?

Comment: As long as it's not Google or any Google related site, you are fine. What cases do you think you are not covering on your own?

Comment: Not sure this is what you need, but you should check out the Selenium code itself and look for the test packages.  These cover a lot of the features and show you how to use some that you wouldn't know of.

Comment: Part of the issue is I don't know what I don't know, hence if there's a set of kata that guide me through the various parts of Selenium I wouldn't feel like I've missed anything.

Comment: @Arran,isn Google - Cheese search the standard example used all across Selenium docs? Why do you think Google and Google Related sites are not a good playground to learn Selenium?

Comment: @amey, agreed, but it is wrong in my opinion. Gmail, in particular, is the worst site imaginable to automate. Google Shopping is another one I'd encountered is awful for automating. Why? The markup of the page is so incredibly complex, especially for beginners it can make it seem overwhelming, thus people tend to think "this is too hard" and give up - it isn't! Just choose the right sites to automate against!

Answer (score 2):

you could install [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) on your computer (very quick), create a couple of fake users and jobs and then use it as a web site you want test. Using a real site on the web could be annoying (you need network connection, you might have delay, they might change something). Having your own local Jenkins would be more handy. And there are many many people who are familiar with the tool, so they could show it to you if you don't know it yet.